# Which kind of CSS rules should I use for this specific layout

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm a very beginer in CSS, I've read a lot of things about it (flexbox, grid,...) but I'm still not sure about which strategy should I use to achieve what I want.

I need something responsive to present a title, a description and a photo. The full width page layout has to be like this:

Title 
                             IMAGE
Description

All those elements are dynamic and should respect the same layout.
The image height should be larger than the title + description height. The title should be able to overlap the photo when the screen is narrower to stay on a single line. When it's really too narrow (i.e mobile screen), I would like to change the layout with media queries to do a single column with this layout:

Photo 
Title 
Description

What is the best approach to achieve this ?

Thanks in advance and sorry if my english is not perfect. Hope it's clear enough ;)

Comment: Imo the best way would be to actually try to implement it yourself, and then ask questions that include your attempts when you hit a wall

Comment: you need to use `media queries` and use `flexbox` in combination with `flex-order` or `css-grid` in combination with `grid-areas`.

Comment: Yes you're right that's because I'm not at home and I wrote this with my phone... The main problem I'm facing is about the title which should be able to overlap the photo to a certain point. Is it possible to achieve this with flexbox or grid ?

Answer (score 0):

use what you feel comfortable.

you can overlap things by using z-index, negative margin

advance way you can use grid

Comment: you can watch this tutorial https://youtu.be/HFG3BKOqOlE

Answer (score 0):

I guess this would work, but might not be accurate as your description was not clear.

```css
img {
  margin-left: calc(25vw - 16px);
  width: 50vw;
  height: auto
}
#title {
  font-size: 50px;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
```

```html
<div id = 'title'>Title</div>
<img src = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD/2wCEAAoHCBUVFRgWFhYYGBgaHBkaGBocGBwcGBoaGhoZGhgaGBocIy4lHCErHxgYJjgmKy8xNTU1GiQ7QDs0Py40NTEBDAwMEA8QHhISHzQrJCs0NDQxNDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0MTQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQ0NDQxNP/AABEIALEBHQMBIgACEQEDEQH/xAAbAAACAwEBAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAwECBAUGB//EADoQAAEDAgMECAUEAgEFAQAAAAEAAhEDIQQxQRJRYXEFIlKBkaHR8BMykrHBBhRC4WLxFSNTssLiFv/EABkBAAMBAQEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABAgMEBf/EACsRAAICAQMEAgEDBQEAAAAAAAABAhEDEiFBBBMxUSJhFAUykSNCcYGhFf/aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A+TseQpN10cRhHDNnG2nv8rCRs5haJo1ljlF0y9GILTrlzUMpSYUtM5K7S45WOvFOhqnQxtEtuTE8R9lLmd6qDPzZ8c/FVe0g2KmmabJbIHYcHQ++KzPokLdSrR8x99y0PaHCzxyMeR1RdeQ7cZK15OS155qWs1WitRM6dxVGkixCsxcXF7l3w6DHAplPDTeQBqSlTyUsBmRP5RRaau2hrxIIGnmsL2rosZORM8rrO+h90kE02ZqZuCtj6JgO0KQGQVvp4hoaWOyN2ncd3IgDl4pvYMcU7UjIasCNVQ71NRku8U1lOW98JipvYdhhII4W+6RUpRK00WGQNQVeo0yZGYtyhTybONxMbwC0Gb5ZXSWpr27koKkYPyOLZCQ/JPo7lV7EA1aM0KWqzmqaIumjKtyz2JcJtQpcJjfkq8KpCY4KjggllWNlONhxVqVM6CUPZGaAraxOzK6OFbsQcoafEysTDcaJ760tPgPX8pSVmmNqLsVialuclZ2tnO25Nc2yoXwlQm7dsfSxI/y8VatUB+UjiFkLCFYpaSu5KqYEH+lZrt89xUMeRvWhotafKEBFWLBk5nvTSw6zKr8NMa+bFBaXsKbJsUPoRldPDFaowQlZro2MzXxNilxOq0jDyLZ7pVW0SCnaIcJc+BRYVqwuFnPuTLaqdqWwMwi7NIwinYjEU4mNLJLHRc9/qF0mYfaE+SvVwrQ0HxSsrtN/JHMe2YgFKLCtTWlpLbwtFPDg+7p2Z6GxGFw21c+f4U1RsOIEFuY71qxD9iw1Ejgk4ZgfDctB/fndC9l6UvivJfAO64dGXcE3FEEmJiZnVx3clbGUdgtYPmF3eFgppUgW5qdvJvGLScDmvp3nRKq07zoVrxLCDATKTAWOmc58k7pWc7x3Jo57DBlMYJlXNEjl+FejCpkKLTpmGq1VohOxISW2CaMJqpFXlXY20pcSnPyhMlb2xRVQFYoTJHU62zlnI/pKc6UtXSHbexdrYBJ4fkqtNpPvJXebHujwzVmMzGVh4lKylG2Q5s5f0qmi3ertbItos1QXUtltUvBdpnNQ1kclRrk1pTJTstUZBzB4hNoPAnilvqTmZ+6oCQgu0naNNip+GktdK3bUtGUxeJ80nsaxqRG3aN3D8qhuq1Coouv95Sopy3odSZfNamU5t3BZ3G9vfehr3Z3Klo2g0nTL12QUyg22gVidqxzTG0iISstQ+VrwKZULSPZVXPJJGhyTSAbQpq0y2LdwVJg4uvothsLtOAdY7ylV/nNoAtHDJPZWkbMwdFeqza628AH3vU273NNEZRqJhqU9Ynj6KuHfs81ubROyRdZ24YTn+VSkZSxSTTRq2jUaHkXFiq0KTgSAfe5Wwzwwn7Hzha3NBgtyOZ1Ut1sdEYpq355ObUwxMnXclMbsuh9gVopDadBzEynYjDNJHLvKd1szHRfyic7EgiwuBlxCU5mUJ+JYW20GXJRPVjw/KpPYxlG5OzPVoyslVi6DpiDksrmXjeqTMMkURSwx2C/cYKUQu/icNsUtnfB8lxHMRGWorNh7dL6FBk5KhYtuGZcyDAF/ws1Q3kKr3OVx2szwrBqu1kpjoTJSKtEyeXv3vTqbNqeJvyCgMnqjPXcE+nLWEZ8iDZRI3xx338CGP2ZG8Ge/LwWKpmmvqFISSJnPhEwrNQ16ZY5WVUQiEBW+GYlS0Roih0SGZLSykY097lShUAkOEg+XFMcyIEg7j9uSGbQSSsrVaQLhI5LsM2QBtDaaQAOsLGL+crDVw1tpmXMH7clKZpPHyijHZLVYi3srCH6QnUzu87IcRQnWxrNXdHEn0XRwr9oCRcZewuVRd1t4W5hAyAnQjdqP9qJRO3Dk5sU55Y+41uPRbmbLnAbQAiDOfcNVhxb7g6/dWwxaTLiQRkENWrHGdSa4s1OwoBkT3Hd5KrMQGwPqGkeCs/FAWBz++4qow+22QRI0t3mNVO9fI1dav6fkfiGAhzpzA2f6WbAQSY+YRIWukzZGzYgg7hHO8a+aw0BsvIyPOERdpoeS002v8j62FLi4xcaow7C2zvlmMwRNtCBotmGp1CTPykGE97Glsm3LKZ0jJQ5PwarEn8vDODiG7LwZj3/a10sU4ujZDpsTGQ+0Roo6RwxiYyWnAUnhhG005ZFp8IJWjacbOWEWsrj/ALOZjGaD2Csz6nVjculjKUaQdeRXN2eacXsZZYNS2CCQLk+CRk9vAiV0sM09kd6z1GdYmNypSM5Y2qZ2OmfkEbh9l54NXdxry+m08vysAZAyWeLZHR1q1zTXpGTFvDeq06yeawkJ9dhlVpsXQtkeXO3KgZTsquYnuEBVLoUuRXb2FU6ZBBdkTHE71OJqz9lR75VCEVfkTelUhLlUtTXNVCE2YNBsqYTIRCZekqCU34kquypDUArGWOSa12mX5571nDUwSnRaYxwIFjbcppYoixynRUVdhFIepp2jVXjMAX1yPNZqjJvmrAKWoSoG78kUXkarWzFDvWZwVQxDSYRlKPg3scHCR4Krnb/9cQsrSQn03mb3S0mqyWJqOIMTyW/AYxzTbO+VvZWauwEpbeqbEEcJ/ICHFNBHJKErR6XD4pjzsyA45RIHKDvvZKxWAghxPVO657gsGDcCIgTofRdZ+KDWbBgzMkm8cCL8Fzyjpl8T0454zh8jLVxDWtGySY/iT5q1GoyoLuO0ZsJ3G4XLxLgTZIY8tIIJEZLTtpo5X1bUt1aOpWrkdR5Ovdpfgt2BwzXMlr4dwtuXArVHO6ziSTmdVo6PrvBhsj7d6JQ+OwQ6hOdtWuPZ3amFlsuN7iTGYzBWL/jTsksG1ff6ZKzsfsNIkEnfYep8kjDdMFhtyy6scpvF/HNYqEvKOyWfE2kzG+RYgghDDNvNegq021Wg7ADjqJiO9cx+EI5DXS/EJqSarkl4WnqTtENqbTA2Dn5IexplsxAtuKe+jsMJJiLNP8TPGVhpsM8AJO6PZCI1TYZFK0mjBXErM4wVqeZM6TYarLWP9LTVsefKFNsqXqM1NKmSU11KM1OpWPRJqzNsqHBOcxR8OOKuzJwM5CrsJziqkJOTI0of8JBpLoNoqww6eo17RzRSU/CXSGGR+2T1i7LOcGKwpreMOrDDp6h9lmAU1b4S3toJgoI1jWJnNFJSKK6Qw6n9sjWHZZzfgo+EuoMMqV6YY0uOQRrQPE0rZzvhpb6jWmC4A7pusGK6Vc6Q0bIyzk9x7wufz9z9lLmc8pLg7jukaYmSSeAse9YanSTjk0AeJWEoiVDmyXKUjUzpOo27XRxAEqzek60k7cyIvBHgVmZTlWFJQ5MtKRcY6p2vIKw6QfM25RZK+EqbF801NkuLN1HpLR47x6Ldh+kGGwMc7ea4JAUg+8/JUpsSk4s9MxwfcHa81f4B3LzOHruYQ5pg748j6L0HRXSvxXBjwATrOfd6KtbN8c4ydPydPBYtzLZjcd27mu1Rex5kRtAXNgbWvfddct2GhDAQdfeWSylFS3R6WLNLHtLdD+mLsERIzkET3b1zqg2aYz6wkkg+cBdyg8RtOMmSYtPvJJx7GEWvFxzOixTlHajtlonve9HmHls2IHPPvWctJK244gWi/qkMoPziBv8Aea1Ujzp4/lSH0hsCdSkik5xn/SvTBmSffL+k4km144CPNJPctxuKXBnfSDdVlqvC1vpHl90oUb3t33WiZzzi3skZQCdEFhWswMgEkuTsxcKO+KauKS0BqNlZWdyghPwlPwk4NVw1LUWoIz/CV20uCeArgI1DUEZvgq7aK0tCYxinWUoIQyirjDrS1ie1oUubKUEYhhlwv1W/YpR1esYub5Gdka/2vVkryvTvQD69YPaZaRDpIAbs5AWm/enCW+5z9TF6Goq2zx1DDlwm0cbCee+2qvTaz/LanWw1t9jpkclq6SwHwagY5zT8pIbLiAdBbOIKpUc0gMDGtO0JeXG3BxyH/wAwt7s8bTTpgcMxwAYetFwZm0k6Wtv4c1BwRmAJN5aLkRxGfNSwlvySD/KCC0xcFrpN89TZdChiQcw4OtsAfLHWueOXmokzfHC2ZMPhSYgj0P8ArVbsPgJ/iSYNhawFnX0nPd5DodHYUv0bDWtzP+JgZ65wNZ4rus6Pf87BsSIAbIIGnP5fFc08tHpY+mjVs8W/Am5AMb9nTWBNwPVZH4VxJGZgk8xmJyOXJe2xXRRaNghoJkhxtkIgEb4nfYjVcCvDHdYWl4OyTvbOuWUclcMlmWbAkrRyBgZbNoAkxnlcQY8uCTWDLbO65vv1tM5SL81vxOIJJDGlok7BJgwCSNqLHS29c97RBcItfrHrOOsLdM8+UaIbTa4mOqP8jbUxIzOWirh3mnUaZHVOuW68TZOrPa4E7DWG0bM23y2fONEhjHPIY1pLiYG8kmI3KjNedvJ9Fw7NtoNiM5Bt4pwpxYJPQPR/waLWkmcyJBAJuQOC6jqYsYWDlue3FNxTkqZmo9HvdfIJv7BozdJ5j/a6nxmlsADLXeuVVw73bXWb3GR3rKeWR1YMON7tnPxOEpTlJGQXPxNzFrbshzOfdmuu7BBubp4wfSIWd2GYBm3wM+SyjJ3Z3SUKpHFdTcTA8de7crsov0HeuoKbMs+4prHxkw+AC21nI8e+yOSOjXu3++KaOhjqPE+krrtrkaeZKW/EvOQ8Afyju+iX01q2jk1OigM48PVZXYVo3eS6dcVD/E+S51ShUnTxWkZ+zmy4GvCOuHKZXhBin9t/1O9UDE1O2/6j6rft/ZwLrPo94FaV4MYp/bf9bvVSMQ/tv+t3ql2yvzfo95KsHrwQxD+2/wCp3qpFd/bf9R9Udq+R/m/R9AYVoavnQrP7bvqPqrCq/tv+o+qXYfspdb9H0ljU4MC+aNqP7bvqPqrte/tu+o+qT6Z+yl1ifB9CehjV4Njn9o+J9VqZtn+R8SjsNcmsc98HqMZ0LRqElzG7REbQEOyjMZ23rF/+cogNaGuGyLHadxuQbTfdoBlZctlN+8pzKTt/n/SSg48j0Qk7aN7v00wU3tY57Q68ANdOzcANIE3A1BOU5RyKn6brU2F5gsEkg9UgW6xbkMzYH+I5LexjtT5rTSJ3qZRfsqPTRu1sHQvRVaZaHAgTcOaYIuJI1uOMFfSf0u+m1kOADgI6wAIGto5eC8XhXnf77lj/AFP0o+mxmy4iS4E8IC5JRkpWi8+HVCm9jvdPYM1ah+EC1sOE3Ddk5i1jyXi8R+nq739VpzglwLQNM3Z6/LOVpXr6tYxEm1h3Lm1nOzkoxp+TVYPhpb2OTQ/RMmatWRaQ1oJsLddwNhOUaDu6A/R+HuNkwZEbWm6c++ZS31H9p3ifVZKmIq9t/wBTvVdOmb5MH00I8Wdan+ksOC3/AKY6oIFyRB7V+tzK3M6Kp0/kaxvJoH2XlH163bf9Z9Uh+Krf9x/1u9UuzN8iWiDtR/4ez+EFBpheDqYut23/AFuWd2Mrf9x/1u9VS6eXsUupguGfQHODbysj8X/lHcF4R+KqnN7/AK3eqS6vU7b/AKj6pS6SUvLFHr8cP7We6fiZ/ke8D8BIOJj+Xl6leJNd/bf9R9VQ139t31FL8Nrkp/qkOIv+T3AxQ7Tj3+gVnYoD3J814P8Acv7b/qPqoOJf23/U71R+K/Yf+rGv2v8Ak92ccqPx/uV4U4h/bd9R9Us139t31FUuk+yJfqkfT/k9nWxnEeKyOxQ7Xl/S8t8Z/bd9RUGo7tHxKpdPXJi/1JPgqFMKqsF1nkokBWVQpDkirLqwCXtKwKY0xjVdqUHK4emikx7SmNn2Cswfy70xruCClI2U3rVSf7n+1z2VDx8QnMdz+lpSaNoZKOox59hObU9+wuYypGo+gjusQnU6vL6j5XWbidMMp0W1FZlWDmufUxbGgy4cdqZ+y5dfptoJ2RPHT3mspI3fURj5Z7ShX5e+S4f6zryynwc7/wAf6Xn39PVTkQPFZMRjnvs520M+9ZqDu2Rl6yEoaY3Z9PZidoTIVXulfPKXTdZggOByzE5ZJtP9S1gbwRuuPMJRg0arr8Vb2e0rFYalRcml+pGOs8FuW880796xws4HvMf+WfBbRXsUuohL9rNT6iTUqHXzCzvre4P/ALEpL38OVmj8LVROaWZlqtTl4rM9x9/6UvefZ/pIc/3K0SOWU7BxPuyW8qC/l75Jbn8SgzciSqFBKpKCLJKqQguVZSFYEKCEEqCglshQplQgkJQoCkIAlWCrKoawCG6GOBUwsrq5VHPJ1UakOzYXgao/cN3+SwoRqYrNxxTRvUfvB2SsSEamGpm4dIf4+aazpSP4n6v6XMQEtTKUmjq/8sez5+gCz1ukHutkNwyWRCTbZWqT5Jc8nMkoBUIU0TZYORtKqEUO2X21UuUIQFsJUtcRcGFCExGlmPeBAPl7jNX/AOTfw8/VY1Up2w1P2bj0gTm0ear++/xCxoT1MWpmz95wUfu+B8VkQjUxWzX+5HFWFRp1WJCephZu2goKxtcRkVcVihSQWPQUsVQVeVadiBRKCoQBT4ig1UtCz1MCXOJzUIQpAEIQgAQhCABCEIAEIQgCQVKqgIHZZChSgoEIQlQAhQolMTZZQoQgVkkqEIQIEIQgAQhCABCEIAEIQgAUglQhAFxUKn4iWhPUwBCEJACEIQAIQhAAhCEACEIQAIQhAAhCEASFKEIKQIQhAypQhCCAQhCABCEIAEIQgAQhCABCEIAEIQgAQhCABCEIA//Z'>
<div id = 'content'>Donec i saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went crizzle i'm in the shizzle maurizzle. Phasellizzle black pizzle boom shackalack nibh pretium tincidunt. Maecenizzle crackalackin fo shizzle. Vestibulizzle in lacus sizzle mauris elementum tristique. Nunc uhuh ... yih! shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle sit dizzle my shizz ultrices shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle. Fizzle velizzle tortizzle, ultricizzle at, quis, adipiscing pot, dui. Break yo neck, yall velit yippiyo, aliquizzle fo shizzle my nizzle, break yo neck, yall pizzle, dictizzle sizzle, sure. Shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle neque. Shiznit lorizzle. Proin vitae erat izzle libero mammasay mammasa mamma oo sa i saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went crizzle. Things boofron augue eu away ullamcorper mattizzle. Fo shizzle fermentizzle daahng dawg non erizzle. Suspendisse dawg my shizz, sollicitudizzle sed, you son of a bizzle id, away nizzle, justo. Donec uhuh ... yih! porttitor crunk. Nunc feugiat, tellus stuff ornare gangsta, sapizzle metus funky fresh go to hizzle, eget gangsta pede mah nizzle izzle doggy. Mah nizzle stuff leo, dope izzle, tempus izzle, fo shizzle izzle, gangsta. Ut fo shizzle my nizzle magna boom shackalack ipsizzle. Sizzle ante nibh, suscipizzle ass, vestibulizzle izzle, bling bling eu, fo shizzle. Shizzlin dizzle a mauris. Sed non magna funky fresh amizzle risizzle iaculis boom shackalack.

Praesent i saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went crizzle turpizzle ut leo break it down pot. Dang vestibulizzle tortor crackalackin tellivizzle. Quisque fo shizzle ornare magna. Morbi commodo, nisl nec bibendum shizzlin dizzle, magna dolor vestibulizzle funky fresh, izzle auctor own yo' dolor quis shit. Maecenizzle its fo rizzle elizzle sheezy amizzle for sure adipiscing sagittizzle. We gonna chung tempizzle pede ut lacizzle. In rhoncizzle get down get down leo. Lorem ipsizzle fizzle we gonna chung amet, consectetizzle ghetto elizzle. Phasellus nisi ligula, we gonna chung yo mamma , sheezy sizzle, tristique mattis, fo. Curabitizzle gizzle faucibizzle crazy. Ut gangster leo. Nunc fo shizzle risizzle a accumsizzle boofron. Quisque condimentum metizzle fo shizzle bling bling. Get down get down sodalizzle, nisi quis gangsta bling bling, lectizzle diam dizzle felizzle, i'm in the shizzle tellivizzle i saw beyonces tizzles and my pizzle went crizzle nisl quis nisi. Away leo quizzle, fizzle sit amizzle, ornare vitae, pulvinizzle pulvinar, shizzle my nizzle crocodizzle.</div>
```

Comment: Next time please post a more clear description and some code. An image would also be helpful, if possible.